# Why I can't run the Snipping Tool from WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a WPF Window with a lot of buttons, each of them run a different program. To run MS Word, for instance, I used:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\WINWORD.EXE");
```

But when I try to run the Windows 7 Snipping Tool the same way it doesn't work. It was supposed to be like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\SnippingTool.exe");
```

I'm sure the path is correct, but always appears a message saying the file wasn't found. I would like to know why is this happening.

Important: I use Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: who is showing a message that the file wasn't found.  is that what the exception says?

Comment: I tried running "C:\\Windows\\System32\\SnippingTool.exe" from explorer on Win7 x32 and it says Windows can't find [...]
Please ignore this. C:\Windows\System32\SnippingTool.exe works just fine.

Comment: @sneakthief: No magic involved as long as no one changes `PATH` from under you.

Comment: Process.Start("SnippingTool.exe") give me the same exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
// if the build platform of this app is x86 use C:\windows\sysnative
if(!Environment.Is64BitProcess) 
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\SnippingTool.exe");
else
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe");
```

The problem is in your build platform (x86) and the automatic redirection of the folder `C:\Windows\System32\` on 64-bit OS'es.

Basically, for several reasons, in vista/windows 7 64-bit OS'es when a 32 bit application try to access to `C:\Windows\System32\` it is automatically redirected to the folder called `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`. Hence, you cannot start `snippingtool.exe` because it is not present in that folder.

The only way is to use `C:\Windows\sysnative\` and bypass the redirection.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you very much for all of you guys!

Comment: this is a weird answer. there are utility classes to do this.

Comment: @DanielA.White: if you meant the platform checking, you're right I forgot the Enviroment property (edited). About the hardcoded paths, I also don't like them very much... but I couldn't find a better way to get the same result...

Comment: @DanielA.White: there's no way to get `C:\Windows\sysnative` using that method... or at least I couldn't find it...

Comment: And this explains why the shortcut doesnt work in my RocketDock!  This just solved an issue I have been annoyed with for a while.

Answer (score 3):

My psychic debugger tells me that you are running a 32-bit program on a 64-bit version of 
Windows, so your call to `%WINDIR%` (`C:\Windows`) is actually being re-routed to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Use the environment variable instead of hard-coding paths to directories that may move around depending on the environment and/or Windows version..

Comment: Ok, but how can I do that (I started programming C# a week ago...)?

Comment: From my experience the debugger you're using is sketchy at best. ;)

Comment: @kenny: Sometimes it's the only debugger available, though I appear to have been correct.

Comment: @RodrigoGuedes: There are a few ways.  One is to grab the value of the environment variable, but .NET gives you another option.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.systemdirectory.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should use an environment variable instead. Likely you are running it on a 64 bit system and `C:\Windows\System32\` is getting redirected.