# Poco::File::exist always return false

Tags: c++, poco, poco-libraries

Anybody got this problem. File always return false for file exist:

```
std::string filePath = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe";
Poco::File file(filePath);
bool exist = file.exists(); // Should return true. But alway return false.
```

Comment: Have you tried with other files?

Comment: isn't it `System32` ?

Comment: This relate to issue from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993733/system-io-file-existsc-windows-system32-snippingtool-exe-returns-false

Comment: answered here for wpf but it is the same directory problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745608/why-i-cant-run-the-snipping-tool-from-wpf

Answer (score 3):

Answered [here](http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=6516&sid=6a4c7e5d46e9a5a8b319f10dc20be82c#p12052):

Is your application 32-bit but you are running on a 64-bit system?
If so, use

`"C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\SnippingTool.exe"`

See [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for explanation why.